# Three dimensional spherical space form

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

How can we deduce the three dimensional spherical space form conjecture from the Poincare conjecture? More precisely, how can we deduce using the Poincare conjecture that every free action of a finite group on $\mathbb{S}^3$ is equivalent to an orthogonal group action. If the proof is involved, then kindly suggest some readable reference for a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't deduce this from the Poincare conjecture, but it follows from the geometrization conjecture/theorems for manifolds and orbifolds. I assume (though I haven't checked) [Morgan-Tian](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4040) talk about this.

Comment: Many thanks. Though I have accepted your answer as final, I would appreciate if someone suggests some short article regarding my question as I am not an expert in this area.